# Problem simulating a key press on Python for Symbian platform on a Nokia 5th ed phone

Tags: python, symbian, nokia, pys60

I am developing an app for Nokia 5800 Music Express (S60 5th edition) using PyS60 (Python for S60) ,I want to simulate a KeyPress say if a message comes,I detect a message and Press a Key.

There does exist a Keypress module for PyS60 for 2nd edition phones which allows this. However I have not been able to install it on my 5th ed phone. Is this module portable? If yes then how do I install it (I get certificate error) and If no then any alternatives for simulating a key press on a 5th edition touch phone?

Answer (score 0):

There are compatibility breaks between 2nd and 3rd editions so binaries developed on one won't work on the other.

There's also a [keypress module for 3rd edition](http://wiki.forum.nokia.com/index.php/How_to_simulate_a_keypress_in_PyS60). It should also work on 5th edition but I haven't tested it myself.

Comment: when I try and install the keypress .sis file on my phone it says certification error. and when I tried from another source it said "Application not compatible with this type" and says "Access not granted".

Comment: @abhishekbhardwaj007: "Application not compatible" message comes if the SIS doesn't contain a special dependency to a S60PlatformID component which has different UIDs on different platform versions. You can safely ignore that. The other issues are there because your SIS file is not signed. Open Signed online https://www.symbiansigned.com/app/page/public/openSignedOnline.do probably works for your needs.